# JDBC driver throws "ResultSet Closed" exception on empty ResultSet

Tags: java, sqlite, exception, jdbc, resultset

I have a problem in JDBC driver for SQLite.

I am executing a query with SELECT statement.

If I get an empty `ResultSet` (0 rows) then I see a "Closed ResultSet" exception thrown when calling `getString(1)`.

Without much prior JDBC experience, my theory (which I could not confirm via JavaDocs for `ResultSet`) is that

- `getString(1)` does NOT work on an empty (zero-row) resultset (by design or due to a bug)
- `ResultSet`'s "open" flag is set to `false` on zero rows (again, by design or a bug)

I saw this [bug report](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlitejdbc@googlegroups.com/msg00702.html) but am not sure if it's related.

My qeustions are:

1. Is the theory above correct?
2. Is it a bug? Feature? (and if so, can someone point to documentation please?)
3. Is it specific to SQLIte's JDBC or to generic `ResultSet` in all JDBC drivers?
4. **What is the correct way of doing stuff like that?**?

For #4, my solution was to use `isFirst()` call right after `executeQuery()` to check whether any rows are there in result set. Is this the best practice approach?

(I could also have simply selected a count insetad since I didn't really need a result set, merely zero-nonzero flag, but I want to know the correct thingh to do if I did care about select's results)

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone! Very illuminating!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Empty or not, but doing the following is always **faulty**:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
string = resultSet.getString(1); // Epic fail. The cursor isn't set yet.
```

This is not a bug. This is [documented behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--). Every [decent JDBC tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=jdbc+tutorial+-site:roseindia.net+-site:tutorialspoint.com+-site:javatpoint.com+-site:javabeat.net) mentions it. You need to set the ResultSet's cursor using `next()` before being able to access any data.

If you're actually interested whether the supposedly unique row **exist** or not, then just check the outcome of `next()`. For example in a fictive `UserDAO` class:

```
public boolean exist(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    boolean exist = false;

    try (
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
    ) {
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);

        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            exist = resultSet.next();
        }
    }

    return exist;
}
```

If you actually expect only **zero** or **one** row, then just do something like:

```
public User find(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    User user = null;

    try (
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, username, email, birthdate FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = MD5(?)");
    ) {
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);

        try (resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                user = new User(
                    resultSet.getLong("id"),
                    resultSet.getString("username"),
                    resultSet.getString("email"),
                    resultSet.getDate("birthdate")); 
            }
        }
    }

    return user;
}
```

and then just handle it accordingly in the business/domain object, e.g.

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);

if (user != null) {
    // Login?
}
else {
    // Show error?
}
```

If you actually expect only **zero** or **many** rows, then just do something like:

```
public List<User> list() throws SQLException {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    try (
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, username, email, birthdate FROM user");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    ) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            users.add(new User(
                resultSet.getLong("id"),
                resultSet.getString("username"),
                resultSet.getString("email"),
                resultSet.getDate("birthdate")));
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

and then just handle it accordingly in the business/domain object, e.g.

```
List<User> users = userDAO.list();

if (!users.isEmpty()) {
    int count = users.size();
    // ...
}
else {
    // Help, no users?
}
```

Comment: I'm choosing to "Accept" this one due to the breadth of code examples and the doc links.

Answer (score 6):

```
while (rs.next()) {
 // process the row
}
```

Comment: This answers #4. What abiout #1-3? :)

Answer (score 5):

From the JavaDocs for [ResultSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor
>   pointing to its current row of data.
>   Initially the cursor is positioned
>   before the first row. The next method
>   moves the cursor to the next row, and
>   because it returns false  when there
>   are no more rows in the ResultSet
>   object, it can be used in a while loop
>   to iterate through the result set.

You'll need to position the `ResultSet` on a row, e.g. by calling calling `next()`, before attempting to read any data. If the call to `next()` returns `false` then the result set is empty.

Comment: This answers #4. What abiout #1-3? :)

Comment: @DVK It doesn't make sense to be calling `getString` until the `ResultSet` is positioned on a row, so it makes sense that it raises an exception (this applies for any JDBC driver). I'm not sure what you're referring to by the 'Resultset's "open" flag'.

Comment: In Eclipse's debugger, when examining the result set, the "open" member has a "false" value. That is the reason for the "ResultSet closed" exception (not the underlying cause, but the immediate variable that is examined to generate the exception in JDBC source)

Answer (score 1):

For such kind of of problem you might use like that

```
while(rs.next())
{
    String name=rs.getString("Name");
    int roll_no=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Roll"));
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
    }
}

Joptionpane.showmessahedialog(this,ee);
```

Comment: Care to format the post. I have formatted one of your answer, check that and format other answers, if any!

Comment: thanx Paresh Mayani i am new for this site.

Comment: No worries...Keep up contributing!