# How to find out if a Java ResultSet obtained is empty?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, resultset

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn =
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:userdata.db");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * from table WHERE is_query_processed = 0;");

int rowcount = rs.getRow(); 
System.out.println("Row count = "+rowcount); // output 1

rs.first(); // This statement generates an exception
```

Why is it so?

Comment: I just noticed that you said an exception was thrown when you called `first()`. Which exception is thrown? It may be throwing one because you're already used `getRow()`, or it may be throwing one because your driver doesn't support this method, in which case Colin's solution is more likely to work for you.

Comment: @jasonmp: You are right my driver does not support call to first(). I used Collin's solution and it is working for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The pattern I normally use is as follows:

```
boolean empty = true;
while( rs.next() ) {
    // ResultSet processing here
    empty = false;
}

if( empty ) {
    // Empty result set
}
```

Comment: this moves the cursor forward right ? so for further processing , the first record might be missed.

Comment: You would miss the first record if you are processing records after this code. However, I usually process the records inside the same while loop. (Where the "//ResultSet processing here comment" is.) This works as expected and includes all rows. The downside it that you cannot just stick the check into a method.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple method to do it:

```
public static boolean isResultSetEmpty(ResultSet resultSet) {
    return !resultSet.first();
}
```

#### Caveats

This moves the cursor to the beginning. But if you just want to test whether it's empty, you probably haven't done anything with it yet anyways.

#### Alternatively

Use the `first()` method immediately, before doing any processing.
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * from table WHERE is_query_processed = 0;");

```
if(rs.first()) {
    // there's stuff to do
} else {
    // rs was empty
}
```

#### References

[ResultSet (Java Platform SE 6)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first())

Answer (score 3):

You can do this too:

```
rs.last();
int numberOfRows = rs.getRow();
if(numberOfRows) {
    rs.beforeFirst();
    while(rs.next()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (results.next())
```

is used to iterate over a result set.so results.next() will return false if its empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is execution not entering the
>   while loop?

If your ResultSet is empty the `rs.next()` method returns false and the body of the while loop isn't entered regardless to the rownumber (not count) `rs.getRow()` returns. Colins example works.

Comment: but my SQL query returns 1 row. I have run the same query on db directly.

Comment: rs.next() without anything other called before, works for me  (including only 1 row in RS) see also section 5.1.4  at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html

Answer (score 1):

Shifting the cursor forth and back to determine the amount of rows is not the normal JDBC practice. The normal JDBC practice is to map the `ResultSet` to a `List` of value objects each representing a table row entity and then just use the `List` methods to determine if there are any rows.

For example:

```
List<User> users = userDAO.list();

if (users.isEmpty()) {
    // It is empty!
if (users.size() == 1) {
    // It has only one row!
} else {
    // It has more than one row!
}
```

where the `list()` method look like as follows:

```
public List<User> list() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL_LIST);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            // ...
            users.add(user);
        }
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    return users;
}
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813858/sqlite-3-jdbc-driver-throws-resultsset-closed-exception-on-empty-resultset/1814443#1814443) for other JDBC examples.

Comment: What class is the list method from? It's not on resultset

Answer (score 1):

CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT

public static final int CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT

```
The constant indicating that ResultSet objects should be closed when the method Connection.commit is called.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
ResultSet MyResult = null;
MyResult = Conexion.createStatement().executeQuery("Your Query  Here!!!");
MyResult.last();
int NumResut = MyResult.getRow();MyResult.beforeFirst();
//Follow with your other operations....
```

This manner you'll be able work normally.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if it's empty or not while not skipping the first record

```
if (rs.first()) {
    do {
        // ResultSet is not empty, Iterate over it
    } while (rs.next());
} else {
    // ResultSet is empty
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can convert your resultset object into String object and check whether is it empty or not.

```
`if(resultset.toString().isEmpty()){
     // containg null result
 }
 else{
     //This conains the result you want
 }`
```