# Check to see if ResultSet is Null if not then get int

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to be able to get check to see if there is a result in my resultset. Todo this i would execute:

```
if(rs.next()){
    boolean = true;
}
```

However i want to check to see if the value is in the database if so retrieve it:

```
while(rs.next())
     id = rs.getInt("id);
```

How would i go about combining the two? I want -2 to be returned if the resultset is empty.

Thanks in Advance,

Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
id = rs.next() ? rs.getInt("id") : -2;
```

like that?

Comment: Can you please explain this as i have never seen something written like this?

Comment: @Dean: it's a ternary expression with the ternary operator `?:`. It does basically the same as `int id; if (rs.next()) id = rs.getInt("id"); else id = -2;`. Also see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `if-else`:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    return resultSet.getInt("id");
} else {
    return -2;
}
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813858/sqlite-3-jdbc-driver-throws-resultsset-closed-exception-on-empty-resultset/1814443#1814443) for more hints how to handle existence, zero/one, zero/more results.

Comment: Except you really should close the result set, which pretty much requires you to save the result in either case, then close the result set, then return.

Comment: @Jay: I don't know how you close your resources, but I usually close them in `finally` and it will just work fine.

Comment: Okay, I'll buy that. Personally I usually close my connections in a finally block but close ResultSets and Statements in main-line code because I'm too lazy to declare them outside the try block and then populate them inside.