# How to find that a SQL query executed has returned nothing?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.*;
public class searchlink{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    //String link="http://hosted.ap.org";
    Connection con=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    Statement stmtR=null;
    if(con==null){
            SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
            con=SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            stmtR=con.createStatement();
    }
    ResultSet rs;
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select url from urls where url='http://www.topix.com/rty/elyria-oh'");
    while(rs.next()){
    String mem=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Result is "+mem);}
}
}
```

The above program prints the output if the query returns a row. 
If the query does not return any, the program stops without printing anything.

Instead of it getting stopped without printing anything, I want the program to identify that the query has returned nothing and print the output saying something like this " There is nothing returned after SQL query execution ".

How to identify using some method or variable that the query has been executed without returning any row?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
boolean hasRows = false;
while(rs.next()){
  hasRows = true;
  // do other stuff required.
}

if(!hasRows)
{
  // do stuff when no rows present.
}
```

-- or --

```
if(!rs.next())
{
  // do stuff when no rows prsent.
}
else
{
  do{
  // do stuff required
  }while(rs.next());
}
```

keeping in mind that the check if(!rs.next()) will advance the cursor in the result set.  Don't advance it again before you get the values.

Comment: +1 for the elegant second version. Unfortunately, the logic is harder to read, and you missed a semicolon.

Comment: @tc thanks, got that semicolon in there, I always forget them in do-whiles.  I agree it's not immediately obvious what you are doing in the second example.  Like anything else it's all about personal tastes and team standards which side of the readability / elegance spectrum you choose to error on (though thankfully they aren't always mutually exclusive).

Answer (score 6):

The normal JDBC idiom is to collect the results in a collection like `List<Entity>`. The another normal idiom is to open resources in [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so they get properly auto-closed. Your code is namely leaking DB resources by leaving those resources open. If you run this repeatedly in a short time, then the DB will run out of resources.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public List<Entity> list() throws SQLException {
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

    try (
        Connection connection = database.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, value FROM entity");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    ) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Entity entity = new Entity(); 
            entity.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            entity.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            entity.setValue(resultSet.getInteger("value"));
            entities.add(entity);
        }
    }

    return entities;
}
```

This way you can use the usual [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) methods to determine the state of the result:

```
List<Entity> entities = entityDAO.list();

if (entities.isEmpty()) {
    // It is empty!
}
else if (entities.size() == 1) {
    // It has only one row!
}
else {
    // It has more than one row!
}
```

#### See also:

- [Answer with another method examples expecting zero-or-one row, zero-or-many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813858/sqlite-3-jdbc-driver-throws-resultsset-closed-exception-on-empty-resultset/1814443#1814443)
- [DAO tutorial - basic kickoff tutorial how to write JDBC the proper way](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Comment: Thanks Balus... Ur answers are really helpful and very brief.
Hope you will guide me till I become a good java programmer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rs.hasNext())
{
    while(rs.next())
   {
    String mem=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Result is "+mem);
   }

}
else
{
   System.out.println("There is nothing returned after SQL query execution ");
}
```

maybe~

Comment: I don't believe the ResultSet will be null, but rather instantiated and empty.

Comment: Still not right. "rs.next()" will move it to the next row. You mean "rs.hasNext()"

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
   System.out.println("no data is returned");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first (rs.next()) will tell you if any data was returned.  React to that one, then loop through the rest (if there are any).

Below I extract the logic for what to do when there is a row into a separate method, and then call that after the "if" and within each "where".

```
   . . .


   ResultSet rs;
   rs=stmt.executeQuery("select url from urls where url='http://www.topix.com/rty/elyria-oh'");
   if (rs.next() {
      printRow(rs);
      while(rs.next()){
          printRow(rs);
      }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no data returned");
    }
  }

  static public printRow(ResultSet rs) {
    String mem=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Result is "+mem);}
  }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a counter in your loop...

```
int count = 0;

while ( rs.next() )
{
    count++;

    String mem=rs.getString(1);   
    System.out.println("Result is "+mem);}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

then ...

```
if (count==0)
{
    // show your message "There is nothing returned after SQL query execution"
}
```

Any call to `rs.next()` moves the cursor so `if (rs.next() == false)` would bump you one ahead and make you skip the first result if you had 2 or more or miss it entirely if you had one result.

Good Luck,

Rick

Comment: Which fails if it returns 2**32 rows.

Comment: With all due respect the statement while(rs.next()) works for 0,1,many results... count is incremented for any scenerio of 1 or more so testing count for non-zero yeilds the answer that you either found 1 or more records or none.  At least thats what it looks like to me.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean got_result = false;
while (...) {
  got_result = true;
  ...
}
if (!got_result) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for select queries in you can do

```
rs.next();
int value = resultSet.getInt(1);
if (value == 0)
{
        //throw error message
}
else
        //
```