# SQLite - Odd NPE in Bukkit plugin

Tags: java, sqlite, minecraft, bukkit

I'm running into a pretty big bug on an SQL-based Bukkit plugin that uses [PatPeter](http://forums.bukkit.org/members/patpeter.16497/)'s [SQLite Bukkit plugin](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/lib-sqlibrary-database-wrappers-for-all-database-engines.33849/) "SQLibrary". I'm attempting to determine whether a player is already entered into the database using [the first solution from another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814443/1621561). More information can be found on [this forum thread](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/registering-doors-to-players.117065/), but I'll give a brief outline here as well.

This is the stack trace:

[image: StackTrace]

And here is the suspect method, with the line indicated in the stack trace marked:

```
SQLite sqlite; // Set in plugin.onEnable(), which executes before anything
String QUERY_PLAYEREXISTS = "SELECT playername FROM table WHERE playername = ?";
...
public boolean exists(String name) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean exists = false;

    try {
        connection = sqlite.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY_PLAYEREXISTS); // 109
        statement.setString(1, name.toLowerCase());
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        exists = resultSet.next();
    } finally {
        connection.close();
        statement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }

    return exists;
}
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never personally used SQLite, yet I would say that you may have misconfigured the SQLite setup `onEnable()`, because `sqlite.getConnection()` must be returning `null`. Try adding the following code before line 109:

```
if(connection == null) {
   throw new RuntimeException("SQLite connection is null!");
}
```

If you get a RuntimeException when next running it, you should probably look into your SQLite setup.

Comment: Actually, I ended up figuring it out, and I can't remember what the problem was exactly, but essentially I was attempting to use an opening and closing format reserved for another action, such as creating the table or entering data, and not necessarily retrieving from the table. Basically, I was trying to close objects that hadn't been opened in the first place, or something like that. Accepted though, for being the first and only answer. :) Also, onEnable() is a method belonging to the JavaPlugin class, which is specific to Bukkit. But I can see what you meant! :)

Comment: Glad to know you solved it :-) And I know what onEnable is, I make Bukkit plugins too :3